# Forcing update on JTable not working

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable on which I show some info and color backgrounds accordingly. I am however having problems whenever data is changed, the table does't update it's color. Looking trough SO I found several questions saying these examples should work:

```
table.revalidate();
```

or

```
((CustomTableModel)table.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();
```

or

```
table.repaint();
```

or

```
tableModel.fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
```

I've tried these methods inside the tableModel, in the JPanel class holding the table itself and even inside the tablerenderer but nothing seems to work (the table doesn't change a bit)

I've checked if the data received when updating the table changes and it does but the table itself doesn't update. It only does when I restart the application.

I have tried making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  just by copying the code but before I could make it work in the same way it had become way to long and complicated for anyone to understand...

Therefor I decided to upload the entire [project to github](https://github.com/BRHSM/JAVADB) but you may be able to find the error in these classes here:

```
package Interface;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

import DataBase.Booking;
import DataBase.Room;
import Logics.Globals;

public class TablePanel extends JPanel{
    private static TablePanel MainLogicInctance;
    private JTable table;
    private CustomTableModel model;
    private JPopupMenu popup;
    private JMenuItem view;
    private JMenuItem confirm;
    private JMenuItem unconfirm;
    private JMenuItem edit;
    private JMenuItem delete;
    int x=0,y=0;
    public TablePanel(){
        model = new CustomTableModel(getObjectArray(), 0);
        popup = new JPopupMenu();
        view = new JMenuItem("view");
        confirm = new JMenuItem("confirm");
        unconfirm = new JMenuItem("unconfirm");
        edit = new JMenuItem("edit");
        delete = new JMenuItem("delete");
        popup.add(view);
        popup.add(confirm);
        popup.add(unconfirm);
        popup.add(new JPopupMenu.Separator());
        popup.add(edit);
        popup.add(delete);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
        table = new JTable(model);
        MouseAdapter adapter = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() != view && e.getSource() != confirm && e.getSource() != unconfirm && e.getSource() != edit && e.getSource() != delete){
                    x=table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                    y=table.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                    System.out.println(Integer.toString(x)+"|"+Integer.toString(y));
                }
                if(e.getSource() == view){
                    Booking booking = Globals.getBookingByDateAndRoom(x, y);
                    System.out.println(Integer.toString(x)+"|"+Integer.toString(y));
                    System.out.println(booking.toString());
                    if(booking!=null){
                        JFrame frame = new PopupFrame("view",booking);
                    }
                }
                if(e.getSource() == confirm){
                    Booking booking = Globals.getBookingByDateAndRoom(x, y);
                    System.out.println(Integer.toString(x)+"|"+Integer.toString(y));
                    if(booking!=null){
                        Globals.updateBooking(booking.getName(), booking.getSurname(), booking.getPersons(), booking.getBegin(), booking.getEnd(), booking.getRoomID(), booking.getId(), true);
                        TablePanel.getInctance().updateAll();
                    }
                }
                if(e.getSource() == unconfirm){
                    Booking booking = Globals.getBookingByDateAndRoom(x, y);
                    if(booking!=null){
                        Globals.updateBooking(booking.getName(), booking.getSurname(), booking.getPersons(), booking.getBegin(), booking.getEnd(), booking.getRoomID(), booking.getId(), false);
                        TablePanel.getInctance().updateAll();
                    }
                }
                if(e.getSource() == edit){
                    Booking booking = Globals.getBookingByDateAndRoom(x, y);
                    if(booking!=null){
                        JFrame frame = new PopupFrame("edit booking",booking);
                        TablePanel.getInctance().updateAll();
                    }
                }
                if(e.getSource() == delete){
                    Booking booking = Globals.getBookingByDateAndRoom(x, y);
                    if(booking!=null){
                        JFrame frame = new PopupFrame("delete booking",booking);
                        TablePanel.getInctance().updateAll();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        table.addMouseListener(adapter);
        view.addMouseListener(adapter);
        confirm.addMouseListener(adapter);
        unconfirm.addMouseListener(adapter);
        edit.addMouseListener(adapter);
        delete.addMouseListener(adapter);

        table.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
        table.setEnabled(false);
        table.getColumnModel().setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        table.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(0);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(0);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setWidth(0);
        this.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.setAllColoumnsRenderer();
        this.add(table,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    private void setAllColoumnsRenderer(){
        for(int i=0; i<368;i++){
             table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(new CustomRenderer());
        }
    }

    private Object[] getObjectArray() {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Recources/TableData/HeaderData.txt"));
            String s;
            s = reader.readLine();

            StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(s,",");
            String tmp;
            int i=0;
            Object[] resault = new Object[368];
            while(str.hasMoreTokens() && i<368){
                tmp=str.nextToken();
                if(!tmp.isEmpty()){
                    resault[i]=tmp;
                }else{
                    resault[i]=" - ";
                }
                i++;
            }
            return resault;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Object[] getRoomObjectArray(String room,int roomId) {
        Object[] resault = new Object[549];
        resault[0]=roomId;
        resault[1]=room;
        return resault;
    }


    public void addRoom(String roomname,int roomId){
        this.remove(table);
        ((CustomTableModel) model).addRow(getRoomObjectArray(roomname,roomId));
        table = new JTable(model);
        ((CustomTableModel) model).fireTableRowsInserted(0, ((CustomTableModel)model).getRowCount());
        this.add(table);
        this.revalidate();
        this.repaint();
    }
    public static TablePanel getInctance() {
         if (MainLogicInctance == null)
             MainLogicInctance = new TablePanel();
         return MainLogicInctance;
    }

    public JTable getTable(){
        return table;
    }

    public void updateAll() {
        System.out.println("forceUpdateRunning");
        int rowCount = model.getRowCount();
        for (int i = rowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            ((CustomTableModel) model).removeRow(i);
        }
        Room rooms[] = Globals.displayAllRooms();
        for(Room room : rooms){
            this.addRoom(room.getName(),room.getRoomId());
        }
        Booking bookings[] = Globals.displayAllBookings();
        for(Booking booking : bookings){
            this.addBooking(booking);
        }
        System.out.println("Time To Update!! :)");
        table.revalidate();
        ((CustomTableModel)table.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();
        table.repaint(); 
    }

    public void addBooking(Booking booking){
        int begin=0,end=0,current;
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        LocalDate currentDate  = LocalDate.parse(booking.getBegin(), formatter);
        try {
            begin = getDateNumber(booking.getBegin())+2;
            end = getDateNumber(booking.getEnd())+2;
            current = begin;
            while(booking.getRoomID()>=model.getRowCount())
                booking.setRoomID(booking.getRoomID()-1);
            while(current<=end){
                if(Globals.YEAR==currentDate.getYear()){
                    if(current == begin){
                        setCell(current,booking.getRoomID(),booking.getName());
                    }
                    if(current-1 == begin){
                        setCell(current,booking.getRoomID(),booking.getSurname());
                    }
                }
                currentDate.plusDays(1);
                current++;
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int getDateNumber(String dateString) throws ParseException{
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        LocalDate date  = LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);
        return date.getDayOfYear();
    }

    public int getYear(String dateString){
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        LocalDate date  = LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);
        return date.getYear();
    }

    public void setCell(int x,int y,String name){
        model.setValueAt(name, y, x);
    }   
}
```

CustomTableModel:

```
package Interface;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import DataBase.Booking;
import Logics.Globals;

public class CustomTableModel extends DefaultTableModel{

    private Booking[] bookings;
    public CustomTableModel(Object[] data, int i){
        super(data,i);
        bookings = Globals.displayAllBookings();
    }

    public int getStatus(int row, int col) {
        for(Booking booking : bookings){
            System.out.println(booking.toString());
            int begin=0,end=0,current;
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
            LocalDate currentDate  = LocalDate.parse(booking.getBegin(), formatter);
            try {
                begin = getDateNumber(booking.getBegin())+2;
                end = getDateNumber(booking.getEnd())+2;
                current = begin;
                while(booking.getRoomID()>=super.getRowCount())
                    booking.setRoomID(booking.getRoomID()-1);
                while(current<=end){
                    if(Globals.YEAR==currentDate.getYear()){
                        if(current == col && booking.getRoomID() == row){
                            if(booking.isConfirmed())
                                return booking.getPersons();
                            return booking.getPersons()+10;
                        }
                    }
                    currentDate.plusDays(1);
                    current++;
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public int getDateNumber(String dateString) throws ParseException{
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        LocalDate date  = LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);
        return date.getDayOfYear();
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
        return false;
    }
}
```

CustomRenderer:

```
package Interface;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class CustomRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
      @Override
      public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {

        JLabel l = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);

        CustomTableModel tableModel = (CustomTableModel) table.getModel();
        //====================Confirmed================
        if (tableModel.getStatus(row,col) == 1) {
          l.setBackground(new Color(255, 128, 128));
        } else if (tableModel.getStatus(row,col) == 2) {
              l.setBackground(new Color(255, 102, 102));
        } else if (tableModel.getStatus(row,col) == 3) {
              l.setBackground(new Color(255, 77, 77));
        } else if (tableModel.getStatus(row,col) == 4) {
              l.setBackground(new Color(255, 51, 51));
        } else if (tableModel.getStatus(row,col) == 5) {
              l.setBackground(new Color(255, 26, 26));
        } else if (tableModel.getStatus(row,col) == 6) {
              l.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        } else if (tableModel.getStatus(row,col) == 7) {
              l.setBackground(new Color(230, 0, 0));
        } else if (tableModel.getStatus(row,col) == 8) {
              l.setBackground(new Color(204, 0, 0));
        //===================Not Confirmed=============
        } else if (tableModel.getStatus(row,col) == 11) {
              l.setBackground(new Color(255, 204, 128));
        } else if (tableModel.getStatus(row,col) == 12) {
              l.setBackground(new Color(255, 194, 102));
        } else if (tableModel.getStatus(row,col) == 13) {
              l.setBackground(new Color(255, 184, 77));
        } else if (tableModel.getStatus(row,col) == 14) {
              l.setBackground(new Color(255, 173, 51));
        } else if (tableModel.getStatus(row,col) == 15) {
              l.setBackground(new Color(255, 163, 26));
        } else if (tableModel.getStatus(row,col) == 16) {
              l.setBackground(new Color(255, 153, 0));
        } else if (tableModel.getStatus(row,col) == 17) {
              l.setBackground(new Color(230, 138, 0));
        } else if (tableModel.getStatus(row,col) == 18) {
              l.setBackground(new Color(204, 122, 0));
        //=====================empty===================
        } else if(col>1){
          l.setBackground(new Color(102, 255, 51));
        }
      return l;

    }
}
```

As of this version of the software I'm trying to update the table from the TablePanel class. but I've tried it in all 3 of these classes.

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omMT2lzfr0g) of it's behavior. I hope I've explained the problem enough and you know the solution?

Comment: You should create a separate MouseAdapter instance for each GUI component, not one for all...

Answer (score 2):

[`DefaultTableCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html#getTableCellRendererComponent-javax.swing.JTable-java.lang.Object-boolean-boolean-int-int-) takes as parameters view indexes. You proceed in the implementation to use these indexes to retrieve values in the model. You need to convert those indexes using [`JTable.convertRowIndexToModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel-int-) and [`JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToModel-int-) first. Then use the converted indexes to retrieve the values in the model.

Comment: wait could you explain a bit better?

Comment: @BRHSM What is shown on screen is the view. What is stored in memory is the model. There is a mapping between the view and the model. E.g. when you sort rows, rearrange colums etc those aren't done in the model but in the view. The view maps to the model. Eg model contains {5,4,3,2,1} and you sort ascending, the view will contain {1,2,3,4,5} but the model remains the same. The view will have row 1 mapping to row 5 in the model, row 2 in the view to row 4 in the model and so on. That is why you need to convert indexes from view to model or vice versa.

Comment: I've tried adding `convertRowIndexToModel` & `convertColumnIndexToModel` to the GetStatus() method before I use the values but it gives me an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on the lines I use them in (line 35 in CustomTableModel)

Comment: @BRHSM That is needed if what you have is a view index, and you want to use that index to look up a value in the model.

Comment: @BRHSM I think you're not using the DefaultTableModel as it's designed. Please read [How to Use Tables - Data](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

Comment: This suggestion is only relevant if you add the ability to sort the data in the table.

Comment: @camickr That is true indeed. It might or might not be relevant, but I don't feel like I need to debug the code by browsing three snippets of code. IMHO it's always best to translate view to model and vice versa where applicable, that way you don't make a habit of not translating and running into problems later on.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you're not calling `super.setValueAt()`. Here is a working example:

```
public class BookingColorChange {

    private static final class AbstractActionExtension extends AbstractAction {
        private final JTable table;
        private final BookingState newState;

        private AbstractActionExtension(String name, JTable table, BookingState newState) {
            super(name);
            this.table = table;
            this.newState = newState;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int[] selectedColumns = table.getSelectedColumns();
            for (int column : selectedColumns) {
                int[] selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows();
                for (int row : selectedRows) {
                    if (table.isCellSelected(row, column))
                        table.setValueAt(newState, row, column);
                }
            }
            table.clearSelection();
        }
    }

    enum BookingState {
        FREE {
            @Override
            Color getColor() {
                return Color.GREEN;
            }
        },
        RESERVED {
            @Override
            Color getColor() {
                return Color.ORANGE;
            }
        },
        BOOCKED {
            @Override
            Color getColor() {
                return Color.RED;
            }
        };
        abstract Color getColor();
    }

    class Boocking {
        private BookingState bookingState = BookingState.FREE;
        private final Date date;
        private final int roomNumber;

        public Boocking(Date date, int roomNumber) {
            super();
            this.date = date;
            this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
        }

        public BookingState getBookingState() {
            return bookingState;
        }

        public void setBookingState(BookingState bookingState) {
            this.bookingState = bookingState;
        }

        public Date getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public int getRoomNumber() {
            return roomNumber;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(30, 15) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.");
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            @Override
            public String getColumnName(int column) {
                c.setTime(new Date());
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, column);
                return sdf.format(c.getTime());
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                return BookingState.class;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
                Object valueAt = super.getValueAt(row, column);
                if (null == valueAt) {
                    int roomNumber = row + 1;
                    c.setTime(new Date());
                    c.add(Calendar.DATE, column);
                    Object dbEntry = fetchEntryFromDataBase(roomNumber, new java.sql.Date(c.getTime().getTime()));
                    valueAt = translateDbValueToBookingState(dbEntry);
                    super.setValueAt(valueAt, row, column);
                }
                return null == valueAt ? BookingState.FREE : valueAt;
            }

            private BookingState translateDbValueToBookingState(Object dbEntry) {
                return null;
            }

            private Object fetchEntryFromDataBase(int roomNumber, java.sql.Date date) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
                super.setValueAt(value, row, column);
                // update your database here
            }

        };

        TableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                    boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                Component rendererComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus,
                        row, column);
                Color color = ((BookingState) value).getColor();
                if (isSelected)
                    color = color.darker();
                rendererComponent.setBackground(color);
                ((JComponent) rendererComponent).setToolTipText(
                        "Room " + (row + 1) + " " + table.getModel().getColumnName(column) + " " + value);
                return rendererComponent;
            }
        };
        JComboBox<BookingState> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(BookingState.values());
        TableCellEditor cellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox);

        JTable jTable = new JTable(tableModel);
        jTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(800, 400));
        jTable.setDefaultRenderer(BookingState.class, renderer);
        jTable.setDefaultEditor(BookingState.class, cellEditor);
        jTable.getColumnModel().setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        jTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        buttons.add(new JButton(new AbstractActionExtension("reserve", jTable, BookingState.RESERVED)));
        buttons.add(new JButton(new AbstractActionExtension("boock", jTable, BookingState.BOOCKED)));
        buttons.add(new JButton(new AbstractActionExtension("cancel", jTable, BookingState.FREE)));
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        jPanel.add(new JScrollPane(jTable));
        jPanel.add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jPanel);
    }

}
```

Comment: @BRHSM what ever you use as persistence backend, I did not analyze your code in depth...

Comment: so that's for like adding stuff to it?

Comment: adding to it works fine. it's the retrieving of the data that doesn't work. meaning it doesn't colorize the table... if you don't understand try watching that video as i show you how the program works

Comment: I did watch the video. Thats why I think you're not updating the table model correctly. But your code is too fuzzy so I rather gave you a working example.

Comment: The problem is you mouse listener. It updates the backend directly instead of the table model.

Comment: @BRHSM but the TableModel should update the backend in its `setValueAt()` method, not the MouseListener.

Comment: @BRHSM, `that's because I've got to also update the data` - the data should be stored in the model. Don't keep the data in two places.

Comment: the data is stored in a database

Answer (score 2):

```
    this.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.setAllColoumnsRenderer();
    this.add(table,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

First of all that is not how you would normally display a table on a panel. Typically a table is added to a JScrollPane so the basic code would be:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The table header and table are automatically added to the scrollpane.

> adding to it works fine. it's the retrieving of the data that doesn't work.

```
public void addRoom(String roomname,int roomId){
    this.remove(table);
    ((CustomTableModel) model).addRow(getRoomObjectArray(roomname,roomId));
    table = new JTable(model);
    ((CustomTableModel) model).fireTableRowsInserted(0, ((CustomTableModel)model).getRowCount());
    this.add(table);
    this.revalidate();
    this.repaint();
}
```

Every time you create a new table or set a new model to the table a new `TableColumnModel` is created. The result of this is that you lose all the custom renderers/editors that have been added to the table.

Firstly, there is never any need to recreate the table. Instead you can just use the `setModel(...)` method of the table. Doing this you never need to worry about removing/adding components from the frame.

However this still won't solve the problem. A couple of solutions:

1. add back in the custom renderers/editor after resetting the model.
2. don't create a new model. Instead you can remove all the rows from the model and then use the addRow(...) method to reset the rows in the model
3. After you initially create the table the first time you can use: `table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false)`. This will prevent the TableColumnModel from being recreated when you reset the model of the table.

Don't create multiple instances of the renderer:

```
for(int i=0; i<368;i++){
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(new CustomRenderer());
}
```

There is no need to create 368 instances of you renderer. A renderer can be shared by all the columns.

Also, you don't need to assign the renderer individually to each column. You can just use the setDefaultRenderer(...) method of the table to set the renderer.

> DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");

Just like the above comment, this code is executed inside a loop. Again a Formatter can be shared. Do keep creating objects that can be reused. Create the Formatter outside the loop so you only have a single instance.

Comment: I tried adding the setDefaultRenderer but now there are no colors at all...

Comment: i'll try to find all places I created the objects inside loops and get rid of them

Comment: Well you are doing something wrong. Did you specify the proper "Class" the renderer should be used for? Why do you even have the `Booking` class in your code. All the data should be stored the TableModel. If you make a change to the data in the table, then you update the backend database.